# Is there a way to update Workbench 2.0 to recognize Mathematica 9, 10 and 10.1 functions?

Tags: workbench, debugging

Is there a way to add newer functions to a configuration file so that Workbench 2.0 is useable for development with 10.1?

Also, are there changes that can be made so that Workbench 2.0 can be used to Debug Mathematica 10.1?

Are there any existing Eclipse add-in that support Mathematica 9, 10 or 10.1?

Comment: No. We all are waiting for Workbench 3.0. Maybe we should start a petition like the [undo](http://undo-for-mathematica.alaifari.com/) one. It looks to me that Wolfram does not take external programmers serious enough, or am I wrong and the release of Workbench 3.0 is imminent? Any comments from WRI?

Comment: We have a beta version of Workbench 3.0 available. I believe tech support will give it to you if you have Workbench 2.0.

Comment: I have the Workbench 3.0 Build 78 Beta.  This was usable but started running into problems with Project files becoming corrupt and could no longer debug or edit files.  Has there been an update since build 78?

Comment: I have obtained a copy of the Workbench 3.0 Beta -  it appears to be the same package (Build 78) that I received a number of months ago.  There were a number of issues with Build 78 - but on-the-whole, it could be used.  I does not appear that any development on WB is happening.

Comment: Cloud Development may be a solution for some developers - development tools may be fairly good here.  In my case - due to contractual concerns on security,intellectual property concerns and a serious obligation to protect data and privacy with real consequences for violation, Cloud Development is a complete non-starter.  There is still a real need for stand-alone development.

Comment: @DougKimzey Try to ask support for a newer Eclipse plugin-version. Maybe they have one.